# Xcode gives different outputs every time (but not the right output)

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a very simple program that reads a file containing text:

```
start
costam
stop
```

The program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
printf("init\n");

char c = NULL;

ifstream file;
file.open(argv[1]);

while (file.good()){
    c = file.get();
    printf("%c", c);
}

return 0;
}
```

xcode build initialized from console gives:

```
init
start
costam
stop?
```

but xcode console gives me:

```
init
```

or

```
init
start
```

or

```
init
start
costam
```

or sometimes nothing. There's no pattern to it. I'm using Snow Leopard with Xcode 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First fix the bug

```
while (file.good()){
    c = file.get();
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

should be

```
for (;;){
    c = file.get();
    if (!file.good())
        break;
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

because you should only check `file.good()` **after** you read, not before. This will get rid of the spurious ? you see in your first output. Whether it will help with the main problem I don't know. Probably not.

Comment: Thank man. It fixed the whole problem. But it's really weird.

Comment: @user2207925 I am surprised.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't mix C I/O (`printf` *et al*) with C++ I/O (`ifstream`). Try this:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << "init" << endl;

    char c;

    ifstream file;
    file.open(argv[1]);

    while (file.good()) {
        c = file.get();
        cout << c;
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```